# mapbox gl add a layer upon met condition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying  to add a Layer to my mapbox map only when a condition is met. In this case, the condition is if a tube station name is guessed correctly, then the Layer i.e. station name corresponding to the guessedStation should be added to the map.

This is my code so far:

```
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
import data from "../../data/tcl.json";

console.log(data)

interface MapProps {
  guessedStation: string | null;
}

const Map: React.FC<MapProps> = ({ guessedStation }) => {
  const mapContainer = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null); //create a reference to a <div> element that will contain the map

  useEffect(() => {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current!,
      accessToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_TOKEN,
      style: "*(hidden)*",
      center: [4.840872, 45.74474],
      zoom: 12.4,
      minZoom: 10.5,
      maxBounds: [
        //coords to limit the map panning
        [4.63, 45.57], // Southwest coordinates
        [5.19, 45.92], // Northeast coordinates
      ],
    });

    map.on("load", () => {
      map.addSource("tcl", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: data as any,
      });

      if (guessedStation) {
        const matchingStations = data.features.filter((feature: any) => feature.properties.nom === guessedStation);

        matchingStations.forEach((station: any) => {
            map.addLayer({
                id: `tcl-label-${station.properties.id}`,
                type: "symbol",
                source: "tcl",
                layout: {
                    "text-field": station.properties.nom,
                    "text-size": 12,
                    "text-offset": [0, -1]
                },
                paint: {
                    "text-color": "black",
                    "text-halo-color": "#ffffff",
                    "text-halo-width": 0.5
                },
                filter: ["==", "id", station.properties.id] // Filter by station id
            });
        });
    }
});

return () => map.remove();
}, [guessedStation, data]);

return <div ref={mapContainer} className={styles.map} />;
};

export default Map;
```

I've tried mapping over the data and adding different conditions